# AS3 - Call function with forEach

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, function, alpha

Flash throw this error in the Output panel:
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property alpha not found on String and there is no default value.

The problematic code:

```
var mcs:Array = new Array();
mcs.push({name:"mc_1"});
mcs.push({name:"mc_2"});
mcs.push({name:"mc_3"});
mcs.push({name:"mc_4"});

mcs.forEach(fade);

function fade(element:*, index:int, arr:Array):void 
{
    fl_FadeOut(element.name);
}

function fl_FadeOut(element:Object)
{
    element.alpha -= 0.05;
    if(element.alpha <= 0)
    {
        element.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_FadeOut);
    }
}
```

I just want to fade out mc_1 then fade in mc_2, hold it for a second then fade out. mc_3 fade in...etc
But I stucked at this error message.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `element.name` to `fl_FadeOut`, which is a string.

I suspect you want to do something along the lines of:

```
function fade(element:*, index:int, arr:Array):void 
{
    fl_FadeOut(getChildByName(element.name));
    //         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Where you use [`getChildByName()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName()) to reference a DisplayObject by its name.